# Why is this axios.get request not working>?

Tags: javascript, json, express, axios

I am currently doing Colt Steele's Web Developer bootcamp and have came across this issue...

In this particular tutorial we are using axios as 'request' has since become discontinued so I'm trying to follow along with this.

What I want to do is set up a Get route for a '/results' page, in this I want to pull information from the OMDB Movie Database and just now, simply show the JSON file when I go onto this Url.

I'm sure there's an obvious solution but I can't seem to figure it our after having searched for hours.

Here is my code;

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const axios = require('axios').default;


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Im listening');
});

app.get('/results', (req, res) => {
    axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=california&apikey=thewdb')
        .then((response) => {
            res.send(response);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('This isnt right');
        })

});
```

As you can see I am also using express, everything is installed correctly. In fact, when I do a console.log(response) like so:

```
axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=california&apikey=thewdb')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('This isnt right');
        })
```

It works, I can see the API JSON in my console, which makes me think there is a problem with using res.send(response) in the promise.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Apologies if I've missed any info out, still fairly new to this...

Comment: Not sure why are doing this , however i think it would be better if you would create a  client class with the axios library and return the results rather than the way you doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get response data for a OMDb request use `data` property:

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    axios.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=california&apikey=thewdb')
        .then(result => res.send(result.data))
        .catch(err => res.send(err));
});
```

For more information, see [Axios's Response Schema documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema).

Comment: Thankyou so much @macborowy, super fast response and works a treat. Much appreciated.